# wandb - Access logged values during runtime

Tags: machine-learning, wandb

How can I retrieve a logged value from wandb before the run was finished?

```py
import os
import wandb
wandb.init(project='someproject')


def loss_a():
    # do_stuff and log:
    wandb.log({"loss_a": 1.0})
    
def loss_b():
    # do_stuff and log:
    wandb.log({"loss_b": 2.0})

for epoch in range(2):
    loss_a()
    loss_b()
    
    # somehow retrieve loss_a and loss_b and print them here:
    print(f'loss_a={??}, loss_b={??}')
```

After run was finished I can find it with `wandb.Api` to get `run.history`. But it seems that before run was fininshed, accessing `run.history` doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve a logged value from wandb before the run was finished by using `wandb.run.summary`. It's a dictionary that holds the last value being logged for a specific key name. Check out this [link](https://docs.wandb.ai/library/log#common-workflows).

You can also check out this [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13IQBMltiXRUbOykbxBDiNLxlDszFf6Ar?usp=sharing) to try it out yourself.

```py
import os
import wandb
wandb.init(project='someproject')


def loss_a():
    # do_stuff and log:
    wandb.log({"loss_a": 1.0})
    
def loss_b():
    # do_stuff and log:
    wandb.log({"loss_b": 2.0})

for epoch in range(2):
    loss_a()
    loss_b()
    
    # somehow retrieve loss_a and loss_b and print them here:
    print(f'loss_a={wandb.run.summary["loss_a"]}, loss_b={wandb.run.summary["loss_b"]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the source code, [`run.history`](https://docs.wandb.com/ref/history) will only hold the data momentarily in `history._data`. As you can see on [this particular line](https://github.com/wandb/client/blob/1d91d968ba0274736fc232dcb1a87a878142891d/wandb/sdk/wandb_history.py#L51), the dictionnary containing the logs is cleared just after the callback is called (I am guessing this corresponds to sending the data to the server via http).

As a workaround, you could return the losses from `loss_a` and `loss_b` and log them at the same time. This actually has the benefit of logging both losses on the same timestep:

```
def loss_a():
   # do_stuff and log:
   return 1.0
    
def loss_b():
   # do_stuff and log:
   return 2.0

for epoch in range(2):
   a = loss_a()
   b = loss_b()
    
   print(f'loss_a={a}, loss_b={b}')
   wandb.log({"loss_a": a, "loss_b": b})
```

This is also a good way to decouple your code from *wandb*!

Comment: this workaround is obvious and not what I need, that's why I've asked the question. loss_a can be located under many functions calls and I'm not interested in returning it all the way to the same scope as loss_b (e.g., logging stuff for debugging). I wanted to know specifically if it's possible to use wandb.log in different places in the code, then peek at what was logged in another place. maybe there's a way to use a buffer before it's deleted, and then explicitly tell wandb when to send to the server and delete the buffer.

Comment: Have you looked at [the source code](https://github.com/wandb/client/blob/1d91d968ba0274736fc232dcb1a87a878142891d/wandb/sdk/wandb_history.py)? The answer is you can't with their current sdk: the buffer is sent and flushed immediately after a new row is added (lines *43* and *44*).

Comment: seems like a feature request is the case here :/ thanks

Comment: If you do, please post a link to your feature request in your OP, thank you!